# Can not get my SWF Flash Banner To Loop

Tags: flash

All I want for this banner to do is loop and start back from the beginning after it finishes. What should be the proper code? What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `File->Publish settings->html tab` check and see if loop is checked. If it is publish the swf and see if it loops.

If you are using swfObject, in the params object that you embed the swf with there is a loop parameter `loop:true`

If you are using the `<object>` tag take a look at [this link from adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html) for more info

Also check and make sure that there isn't a `stop()` action on the last frame of the flash movie